# Serial port settings "TxContinueOnXoff" and a few more. Delphi to C#

Tags: c#, delphi, serial-port

I am writing software in C# to program a two way radio with TX and RX frequencies and optional information. The manufactures program was written in Delphi. I have the HEX protocol information from the manufacture but I had to decompile their program to get other information. For now I just built a simple program that sends a string and reads the radios reply.

I send the radio the startup string and it responds with something crazy, "-P320733?-". Then I send it another string to start the channel information and it gives a "W???????????". The W is correct but the ?s are not and from what I understand that maybe the result of wrong serial port config.

Since the original program was written in Delphi I don't know what some of the settings are and don't know what to set them to in C#.

This is the Delphi port settings. Most things in there are self explanatory while others are not. I'm not sure witch need to be set and how they need to setup and which I can leave out.

```
CommName = 'COM2'
BaudRate = 9600
ParityCheck = False
Outx_CtsFlow = False
Outx_DsrFlow = False
DtrControl = DtrEnable
DsrSensitivity = False
TxContinueOnXoff = True
Outx_XonXoffFlow = False
Inx_XonXoffFlow = False
ReplaceWhenParityError = False
IgnoreNullChar = False
RtsControl = RtsEnable
XonLimit = 500
XoffLimit = 500
ByteSize = _8
Parity = None
StopBits = _2
XonChar = #17
XoffChar = #19
ReplacedChar = #0
ReadIntervalTimeout = 20
ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0
ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0
WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0
WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0
OnReceiveData = Comm1ReceiveData
```

Here is my code for the port.

```
{
InitializeComponent();
serialPort1.PortName = "COM1";
serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.Two;
serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
}
```

I send it the code below and it sends me "-P320733?-". It should return with, 0650333230373333FF06.

```
        byte[] juf = new byte[9];
        j = 0;
        juf[j++] = (byte)0x50;            //start talking to radio
        juf[j++] = (byte)0x52;
        juf[j++] = (byte)0x4f;
        juf[j++] = (byte)0x47;
        juf[j++] = (byte)0x52;
        juf[j++] = (byte)0x41;
        juf[j++] = (byte)0x4D;
        juf[j++] = (byte)0x02;
        juf[j++] = (byte)0x06;
```

After the radio responds, I send it the code below and get back "W?????????". The amount of ?s will vary from 0 to 20. It is supposed to return with "57004040" and "0075024000750240FFFFFFFF00BFA0F8".

```
        byte[] vuf = new byte[5];
        v = 0;
        vuf[v++] = (byte)0x52;           //start channel info
        vuf[v++] = (byte)0x00;
        vuf[v++] = (byte)0x40;
        vuf[v++] = (byte)0x40;
        vuf[v++] = (byte)0x06;
```

Eventually I need to convert radio's response into readable information and display it on a datagridview for the user to see but that's later, right now I'm just trying to make sure the serial plays nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the communication parameters, you have them correctly set. The `TxContinueOnXoff` parameter should have no meaning since `Xon/Xoff flow control` is set to `false`.

You need to make a distinction between ASCII representation and HEX representation of byte values. [Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

If the documentation uses hex representation for sent and received data you should compare the docs with *actual data as hex representation*, not as text.

It seems the first response does match the documentation if looked at as hex. When the documented hex representation is translated to ASCII (except for the non printable characters 0x06 and 0xFF) it is the same that you call 'something crazy'.

```
HEX:   06 50 33 32 30 37 33 33 FF 06  // expected, as hex
ASCII:  -  P  3  2  0  7  3  3  ?  -  // received, as text
```

There is no printable character for 0x06 and 0xFF, therefore, whatever you used to look at the message as text, chose to display `0x06` as a dash and `0xFF`as a question mark.

Just treat the bytes for what they are - bytes, and convert to hex representation to compare/verify with the docs.

Just of curiosity, what is the protocol called, or if it is publicly available, do you have a link to share?

Comment: I guess its not really a protocol we just call it that at work. Its an excel that goes over hex values the radio sends when getting a hex value response from the computer and visa versa. I did get a serial monitor program and found some values on the excel out of place, not surprised knowing its country of origin. Thanks for all the help as it did point me in the right direction and clear up a lot. This is my first time with serial so little difficult and to throw byte manipulation in as well, wow.

Comment: @808EVO Ok, I was thinking about the radio manufacturers spec. or even just the name of the manufacturer. I can then search for published docs.